# Invaild security or form key, please refresh your page

Tags: magento2, admin-controller

i hit the url backendnotification/index/index this error show[image]

what is wrong route and controller

this is my route code

```
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="backendnotification" frontName="backendnotification">
            <module name="Testing_ScheduleContentNotifier"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>

This is my controller code under Testing/ScheduleContentNotifier/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index.php

<?php
namespace Testing\ScheduleContentNotifier\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface as HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
class Index extends Action implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Index action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Grid List'));

        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because you have not create layout for this page yet. To create 1 page, you need create 1 file for controller, 1 file for layout.

You can read this: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ext-best-practices/extension-coding/example-module-adminpage.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this all steps it will useful you

1.Check the form key in your controller action:
Ensure that your controller action contains the form key validation. Add the following code at the beginning of your **execute()** method.

```
if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
    $this->messageManager->addError(__('Invalid request.'));
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    return;
}
if (!$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
    $this->messageManager->addError(__('Invalid form key. Please refresh the page.'));
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    return;
}
```

2.Clear Magento cache:
Run the following command in your Magento root directory to clear the cache.

```
 bin/magento cache:clean
```

3.Verify the route and controller setup:
Ensure that your module's route and controller are set up correctly.
**etc/adminhtml/routes.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="backendnotification" frontName="backendnotification">
            <module name="Testing_ScheduleContentNotifier"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

4.Check file and folder names:

**app/code/Testing/ScheduleContentNotifier/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index.php**

5.Ensure the module is enabled:

```
  bin/magento module:status
```

6.Deploy static content:

```
 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

7.Finally, clear your browser cache and refresh the page.

```
 *Im hope you this is  execute successfully.*
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check Magenot log file**

Run this command in terminal  and re-generate the issue

> tail -f var/log/*

```
Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System -> Security - Max Session Size in Admin and Max

set Max Session Size in Admin: 2560000
```